# Using Pivot for Age Ranges Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table

I am using a pivot to group age ranges from an age column and all of the columns are not being filled as they should. I am taking the sum of LOS (length of stay) and the age range totals should equal the TotalLOS, but currently it is not. Please help!!

This is the T-SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT [Hosp Name], 
    Cnty, 
    Max([Hosp County]) as [FirstOfHosp_County],
    Max(Hosp) as UID, 
    LOS,
    Age,
    Sum(LOS) as TotalLOS,
    CASE    
        WHEN Age <=17 THEN '0-17'
        WHEN Age Between 18 and 64 THEN '18-64'
        WHEN Age >=65 THEN '65 Up'
        ELSE NULL
    END AS AGERANGE
FROM [S1:  Basic Source Query]
GROUP BY [Hosp Name], Cnty, Age, [Hosp County], Hosp, LOS
) AS S

PIVOT 
(       
    Sum(S.LOS)
    for S.AGERANGE 
    in ([0-17], [18-64],[65 Up])
) as pvt
```

I'm converting this query from Access.  This is the Access query:

```
TRANSFORM Sum([S1:  Basic Source Query].LOS) AS Days
SELECT [S1:  Basic Source Query].[Hosp Name],
[S1:  Basic Source Query].Cnty,
FirstOfHosp County:  First([S1:  Basic Source Query].[Hosp County])
UID:  First([S1:  Basic Source Query].Hosp)
Total:  Sum([S1:  Basic Source Query].LOS)
FROM [S1:  Basic Source Query]
GROUP BY [S1:  Basic Source Query].[Hosp Name],
[S1:  Basic Source Query].Cnty
PIVOT Switch([Age] Between 0 And 17,"0-17",[Age] Between 18 And 64,"18-64",[Age]>=65,"65 Up");
```

This is a sample of the Access data before the pivot. It doesn't have all the columns.

```
Hosp      Hosp Name             LOS     Age
HOSP301   Apple Hospital        16      92  
HOSP301   Apple Hospital        5       34  
HOSP301   Apple Hospital        14      85  
HOSP301   Apple Hospital        7       21  
HOSP301   Apple Hospital        4       79  
HOSP301   Apple Hospital        2       26  
HOSP301   Apple Hospital        2       19
```

And once the Access query runs, it turns it into this:

```
UID       Hosp Name             TotalLOS    0-17    18-64     65 Up
HOSP301   Apple Hospital        130                  117      13
HOSP301   Apple Hospital        5                    5  
HOSP301   Apple Hospital        722         60       455      207
HOSP301   Apple Hospital        23          17                6
HOSP301   Apple Hospital        15                            15
HOSP301   Apple Hospital        6                    6
HOSP301   Apple Hospital        3           3
HOSP301   Apple Hospital        32          1        31
```

This is the incorrect SQL results I am getting. The numbers under the Age Ranges should match the TotalLOS column:

```
UID     Hosp Name       Cnty    FirstOfHosp_County    Age   TotalLOS    0-17    18-64   65 Up
HOSP301 Apple Hospital  Apple   Apple                 57    24                  4   
HOSP301 Apple Hospital  Apple   Apple                 68    13                          13
HOSP301 Apple Hospital  Apple   Apple                 69    12                  4   
HOSP301 Apple Hospital  Apple   Apple                 71    10                  10  
HOSP301 Apple Hospital  Apple   Apple                 73    8                   2   
HOSP301 Apple Hospital  Apple   Apple                 74    7                   7   
HOSP301 Apple Hospital  Apple   Apple                 75    6                   6   
HOSP301 Apple Hospital  Apple   Apple                 79    34                  17  
HOSP301 Apple Hospital  Bacon   Apple                 63    2            2  
HOSP301 Apple Hospital  Bagwin  Apple                 68    16                  16
```

So as you see the numbers in the ranges don't always match what's in the TotalLOS column. I believe I didn't convert it correctly from Access to T-SQL.

Comment: There is no point including these fields in the group by `[Hosp County], Hosp, LOS` while [aggregating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173454.aspx) them in the select clause.   Can you provide sample data that returns an incorrect result?  Without it is hard to work on your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your actual problem is, but if you change the SQL to something like this it might work better:

```
SELECT [Hosp Name], 
    Cnty, 
    Max([Hosp County]) as [FirstOfHosp_County],
    Max(Hosp) as UID, 
    LOS,
    Sum(LOS) as TotalLOS,
    Sum(CASE WHEN Age <=17 THEN LOS else 0 end) as [0-17],
    Sum(CASE WHEN Age Between 18 and 64 THEN LOS else 0 end) as [18-64],
    Sum(CASE WHEN Age >=65 THEN LOS else 0 end) as [65 Up]
FROM [S1:  Basic Source Query]
GROUP BY [Hosp Name], Cnty, [Hosp County], Hosp, LOS
```

Edit: Removed Age, it makes no sense as a column.

Comment: AHHHHH!!! Thank you JamesZ.  I didn't need a pivot at all.  I assumed because the Access query had a pivot that I needed one when converting it to T-SQL.  I appreciate your help!